# php mysql - spelling conversion?

Tags: php, mysql, spell-checking

I need to change UK spelling to US spelling for the content stored in the database(mysql). Is there any way to do this on the db itself? I found various software's(like a word add-ins) but to use these I need to have the data in a doc format, do the changes and export it back to mysql. Please let me know if there is a method using php/mysql to change the spellings. Checked out things like pspell and other classes(found through google search) but they do not these conversion of uk to us.

regards

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure there's no possibility to do this in mySQL - it is a task that definitely should not be performed by the DBMS.

If no PHP based solution comes up, there are lists like the one from [**the spelling society**](http://www.spellingsociety.org/journals/j21/usukspell2.php) that *may* allow for automatic conversion to some degree - they even come with variations like

> cudgel +led, +ling > cudgel +ed, +ing

it is far from complete, though.

May I ask what you need this for?